# Access sorting one column on the content of another column

Tags: sorting, ms-access

i already tried a couple of things but i am not improving. I am quite new to Access.

I am trying to sort one column on the content of another column.
Example:

| ID | FID | Txt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | bla |
| 2 | 0 | bla |
| 3 | 2 | bla |
| 4 | 2 | bla |
| 5 | 1 | bla |
| 6 | 4 | bla |
| 7 | 5 | bla |

should end like this

| ID | FID | Txt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | bla |
| 5 | 1 | bla |
| 7 | 5 | bla |
| 2 | 0 | bla |
| 3 | 2 | bla |
| 4 | 2 | bla |
| 6 | 4 | bla |

So my FID is always sorted after the same number in ID.
i hope somebody can help me!

many thanks!

Comment: Don't understand requirement. What logic is applied to produce that output?

Comment: The FID should always be one row under the ID with the same Number

Comment: Sorry, don't understand that. Why is 0 1 row below 7 and 2 below 3? Whatever the logic, the code will probably be complex. Chances are slim anyone here will tackle it. You don't have indicate what programming language you use, shall we assume VBA. You don't show any attempt to solve.

Comment: Sorry, i try to explain it a bit better: The number in FID should sort after the same number in ID. So if my FID is 1 the Data should be sorted under the ID 1. Im doing this cause im trying to do an Task table with Subtasks. So my FID is the ID from the Maintask. To visualize this better the Data from the Subtask should be sorted under the main Task. Example Task ID is 2, Subtasks with the FID 2 are sorted under the ID 2. Im unsure if this can be solved with the Advanced Filter/sort, but i guess a VBA script should also be fine. I was unable to find something similar online, again many thanks!

Comment: Still don't know why 0 is below 7 nor why 2 is below 3 - these are not "same number in ID". This would likely involve code writing records to a temp table. "do an Task table with Subtasks" sounds kind of like tree view.